# Exception starting server on MICO

Tags: exception, corba

I've made server and client using mico, but by trying to start server with

```
./server –ORBInitRef NameService=corbaloc::localhost:12456
```

I get this:

```
uncaught MICO exception: IDL:omg.org/CORBA/ORB/InvalidName:1.0
```

Problem seems to be with NameService.

Comment: Looks you are having a problem in your code, we can't assist you further when you don't share your CORBA initialization code. Have a look at various CORBA examples on the internet, see for example the free [CORBA Programmers Guide](http://www.remedy.nl/opensource/corbapg.html)

Comment: Well you need a Naming service listening on port 12456.
After that you need an entry in naming service if you are trying to resolve something in server.